# Can the human body survive in a zero sugar diet strictly through gluconeogenesis?

Tags: human-biology, diet

I read an article a while back about athletes (I believe cyclists) being exposed to a 0 sugar diet and their blood sugar levels stayed relatively constant, which prompted the question whether people could survive strictly off a no sugar diet.